# How to put the Order BY in SQL UNION so TOTALS will show up always as last row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have SQL UNION where second part of that statement is the row that represents TOTALS. How can I ORDER BY where TOTALS will ALWAYS will show up as the last row?

Comment: can you **SHOW** us the query you have???

Comment: Just by-the-by, you're using UNION ALL not UNION, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add an extra column to the queries being UNIONed, and make that column the first column in your ORDER BY clause.

So if I started with something like this:

```
SELECT product, price
FROM table
UNION 
SELECT 'Total' AS product, SUM(price)
FROM table
```

I'd add a new column like this:

```
SELECT product, price
FROM (
  SELECT product, price, 0 AS union_order
  FROM table
  UNION
  SELECT 'Total' AS product, SUM(price), 1 AS union_order
  FROM table
)
ORDER BY union_order
```

That way, regular products appear first, then the total appears at the end.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't seem to like the ORDER BY after the outer select.

Comment: If I need to order by product asc but exclude total, product with "u" should not appear after total, what would be the way ?

Comment: @user1532976, that is its own question, so I suggest that you ask it as a question so that it gets visibility.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using [`GROUP BY ROLLUP`](http://www.compshack.com/sql/oracle-group-rollup) - it might be just want you want, although it's difficult to tell when you haven't posted your query.

Comment: That's a neat little feature. +1

Comment: Yes -- much more efficient in theory than unions. A half-way-between solution would be to use a subquery factoring clause to compute the detail then reference it in two queries unioned together, one to pass the detail through and the other to do the totals, but group by rollup is better.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding an 'order' column to each query and then order by that column...

```
SELECT x.*
FROM
(
SELECT columns, 2 AS [Order]
UNION 
SELECT totals, 1 AS [Order]
) x
ORDER BY x.[Order]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(
  select 1 as prio
  , col1
  , col2
  ...
  from tableA
     union
  select 2 as prio
  , totalCol1
  , totalCol2
  ...
  from tableB
) order by prio
```